# How is a connection kept alive during long polling with WSGI?

Tags: http, client-server, wsgi, long-polling

I was wondering how a connection is kept alive during long polling. Are KA messages sent to and then responded by the server? I never saw this explicitly written anywhere in the code.A related question is how long can a response be 'held'?